# How to get a 3-year-old to stop running away?

Tags: toddler, discipline, safety

My 3-year-old will break away from me or my husband and he is so fast we cannot catch him. It happens in the house but sometimes outdoors in a parking lot, at the pool or play area especially when he doesn’t want to leave or store which can be dangerous. Any suggestions?

Comment: Here's a related [question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/18825/30519).

Answer (score 1):

Child one of those chest halters those work really well